# Why did I fail to load PBSmodelling package?

Tags: r, installation

```
     install.packages("PBSmodelling")
   Installing package into ‘/Users/apple/Library/R/3.2/library’
     (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
     open URL’http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2/PBSmodelling_2.67.266.tgz'
     Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3361768 bytes (3.2 MB)
       ==================================================
        downloaded 3.2 MB


   package is located:
    /var/folders/gg/zk53_6b10_91l8wnf5y4_blm0000gn/T//RtmpPrc2GY/downloaded_packages
```

The install package is successful, however, when I load the package to workspace, It reported error:

```
      library(PredictABEL)
   need packages：PBSmodelling
     Error : loadNamespace() 'tcltk' .onLoad fail，details：
     use: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
     error: cannot load target object‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so’：:
     dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib
     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so
     Reason: image not found
     else: Warning message:
     run''/usr/bin/otool' -L '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/tcltk/libs//tcltk.so''
error: cannot load package ‘PBSmodelling’
     xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

Comment: "tcltk" package needs installing. Closing this post, see linked post, it has answers to many common installation problems.

Comment: I am trying to install "tcltk" package, but still failed. where is the link to that same existing question? @zx8754